# When using ethtool -S what is the difference between rx_packets and rx_pkts_nic?

Tags: linux-networking, nic, ethtool

`rx_packets` are much larger than `rx_pkts_nic`. Why is this the case?

Is there a doc somewhere with explanation of all the NIC stat fields?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `ethtool -S` is a driver specific. Seems like you use some intel NIC.

Likely you have enabled some offload (`GRO` - Generic Receive Offload, `LRO` - Large Receive Offload). You can check the output of `ethtool -k <iface>`.

In this case several received packets (counted by `rx_pkts_nic`) are merged in a single bigger packet (counted by `rx_packets`). And only then this big single packet is passed into the system network stack.

Unfortunately I don't know the complete documentation with detailed description of various NIC counters. Most of them have intuitive names, but not all. Some of them you can try to understand with the linux kernel mail list messages. Also you can try to write to the mail lists to ask the meanings.

#### Update

I've looked into the source code of the driver and have found some interesting things.

1. The [`rx_packets`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_ethtool.c#L40) counter value is received from statistics of the network device in the system, not from hardware. This value is counted as [sum](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_main.c#L7048) of packets from all NIC queues. This value also includes a bad packets.
2. The [`rx_pkts_nic`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_main.c#L7129) is received from the hardware, but also it [is decremented by `rx_missed` value](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_main.c#L7131). Seems like this value includes only good packets (real name of this counter is [`gprc`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_ethtool.c#L44), that means `good packets received count`).
3. So, if you have a difference between `rx_packets` and `rx_pkts_nic`, check the error counters.
4. Good thing for investigation of NIC statistics counters is the `ethtool --register-dump <iface>` command.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! GRO is enabled but I am wondering why the rx_packets are much larger than the rx_pkts_nic if they are supposed to be a merged count.

Comment: What NIC and driver do you use? Check it with `ethtool -i <iface>`. Maybe the meanings of this counters have been changed. I've read about these counters in this thread - https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/34198/

Comment: What are the counters values? Maybe this is a side effect of high-order bits exclusion or the counter overflowing.

Comment: The driver is ixgbe 4.2.1-k. The nic is Intel x550. rx packets: 2249708870. rx pkts nic: 2247657927